# Problem installing SQLite from terminal using ./configure --prefix=/usr/local

Tags: macos, terminal, configure

just before I start I am following the instructions from this site:
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-set-up-learn-sql-in-mac-os-x-3638150/

When getting to step 4, I get the error:

```
configure: error: invalid value of canonical build
```

This occurs when I type the command:

```
./configure --prefix= /usr/local
```

Wondering what I can do to fix the error. Cheers

Comment: Have you tried without the space? ie: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`. Also, I'd recommend that if your aim is to learn SQL, rather find an install from homebrew than building your own, unless you really want to. The problem with building your own is that nothing will track the installed artifacts, which makes it more difficult to uninstall and (with more complex packages) may cause strange behavior from conflicts down the line.

Comment: Ok will do. Cheers